# MacBook 15-inch speakers on when closed, is it damaging them?

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

I have my MacBook on a stand and I plug in a monitor and listen to something and I occasionally forget to plug-in my speaker. Will it damage my Mac speakers if they're facing the screen ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the device will just be muffled. You needen’t worry about closed clamshell mode if you don’t have other microphones and speakers engaged or selected.

Comment: Thank-you, just didn't want it damaged due to my laziness of forgetting plug-in a speaker XD